# Inequality's root

Tags: inequality

Given $\sqrt x + \sqrt y < x+y$, prove that $x+y>1$.

Havnt been able to try this yet, found it online,

any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}<x+y$, then after squaring both sides we have $x+2\sqrt{xy}+y<x^2+2xy+y^2$. Rearrange to isolate the square root:

$$2\sqrt{xy}<x^2+2xy+y^2-x-y=(x+y)^2-(x+y)=(x+y)(x+y-1)\;.$$

Can you see why this implies that $x+y>1$?

Answer (score 5):

If $x+y\leq 1$ then $0\leq x,y \leq 1$ (since $x,y \geq 0$). It follows that $x\leq \sqrt x$ and $y\leq \sqrt {y}$ which implies that $x+y\leq \sqrt x+\sqrt y$